# What is set-mark in bash and how should I expect it to behave?

Tags: bash, clipboard

It's just mentioned a shortcut for and its usage is supposed to be obvious, but it isn't obvious to me. How do I even tell I "marked" something? Why would I mark something? Does this thing have a scope? Does it ever expire? And do I get a bash warning when/where it did? And above all, cool, I "set mark". What now?

So, what exactly is this mark that I can set and what would I use it for?

Comment: What happened to my comments and is this acceptable on stackexchange?!

Comment: By "comments" do you mean the parts of your question that have been edited out? Take a look at the edit history for your question for an answer to that. (You can find it on the link just above these comments. Currently it reads [edited 6 hours ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/423405/revisions) but obviously that will change with time. Personally I think your original question would have been closed as "Primarily opinion-based" whereas the edited version is a straightforward question with a presumably straightforward answer.

Comment: @roaima I agree that "comments" can (only) be understood that way and I appreciate your attentive explanation, often so needed. I meant actual comments. A while after the editing, the five comments got deleted, including not obsoleted ones (and anyway I thought moderators deleted abuse and let users do their own other editing/deleting). It's actually surprising that you can't see the deleted comments or any mention of the deletion in some log accessible at your 34k+ reputation level. Does this happen? And is there a way for me to recover my messages (to save them locally)?

Comment: I can't see deleted comments. I have no idea whether or not moderators can see deleted comments. This would be a reasonable question to take to [meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `set-mark` isn't a bash command, it's a readline command.  It's used to set a "mark" on a specific location in the command line you are currently editing.

That mark can then be used in other readline editing operations.

Full documentation for readline may not be installed by default. Depending on your distribution it may be in a separate package, with a name like `readline-doc`, in GNU Info file format (requires, e.g., `info` or `pinfo` to view).  It is also available on the web at https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

It is also documented in the bash man page, and in the man pages of several other GNU programs that use readline.  Run `man bash` and search for `^READLINE`.

From `man bash`:

> **Readline Command Names**
>
> The following is a list of the names of the commands and the default
>   key sequences to which they are bound.  Command names without an
>   accompanying key sequence are unbound by default.  In the following
>   descriptions, **point** refers to the current cursor position, and
>   **mark** refers to a cursor position saved by the `set-mark` command.
>   The text between the **point** and **mark** is referred to as the
>   **region**.

Note that readline commands are for both interactive use (i.e. while editing a command line) and programmatic use (e.g. in your `~/.inputrc`).  That is why some of the commands have options/arguments.

BTW, there aren't many readline commands that make any use of *marks* or *regions* (The *point* is used frequently, by many readline commands).  They are:

Two with default key-bindings:

> **set-mark** (C-@, M-<space>)
>
> Set the *mark* to the *point*.  If a numeric argument is supplied, the *mark* is set to that position.
>
> **exchange-point-and-mark** (C-x C-x)
>
> Swap  the *point* with the *mark*.  The current cursor position is set to the saved position, and the old cursor position is saved as the *mark*.

So you can mark the current cursor position with `Ctrl-@` or `Meta-<space>`and swap the mark for the current cursor position by typing `Ctrl-x` twice.  i.e. useful for jumping back and forth between two positions in the line.

and two without default key-bindings:

> **kill-region**
>
> Kill the text in the current *region*.
>
> **copy-region-as-kill**
>
> Copy the text in the *region* to the kill buffer.

To use either of these while interactively editing on the command line, you'd have to bind them to a key.